# Is the notion of proper class absolute?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am curious if there exist formulas with one free variable in the first order language of set theory that represent a proper class in one model of ZFC, but represent a set in another model. In other words, is there some $\varphi(x)$ such that the statement $\exists A \forall x : x \in A \leftrightarrow \varphi(x) $ is true in one model, but false in another model. Please correct me if these two statements and the title are not equivalent.

I believe the answer to this question is yes, as one model of ZFC can include an inaccessible, while another may not. I suspect that some subset of this inaccessible might be a set in this model, but a proper class in the other. However, there seem to be some subtleties here. My primary concern is that any formula that speaks to subsets of an inaccessible might simply be false for every element in the model without an inaccessible (resulting in $A = \emptyset$, and the formula actually representing a set in both models).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Almost entirely trivially, no. But otherwise, sort of yes.

Consider $\varphi$ to be something like "If $V=L$ then $x=x$, otherwise $x\neq x$". So in $L$ this is everything, and in any larger universe it is the empty set. You can change this and play around with this, and even find formulas which can be flicked on and off between set and proper class. For example "If $\sf CH$ holds, then $x=x$, otherwise $x$ is a finite ordinal".

Note, however, that a proper class (in $\sf ZFC$) have members whose von Neumann rank is arbitrarily high, and therefore if you avoid tricks like the above, you are probably going to have $\varphi$ defining a formula in inner models as well, just because of that. If you consider models with more or less ordinals, then this is a different story altogether, and the inaccessible gives an excellent example as you suggested.

Comment: Aha -- duh! It might be a neat example of a 'false proof' to universally instantiate a 'set' defined in such a way.

Comment: True, but it's really like the usual "set which ZFC cannot decide on its content" where you define it to be empty if CH holds and 1 otherwise. Just with proper classes.